# Use content from multiple elements as their width

Tags: jquery, html

I'm relatively new to jquery and I'm having trouble doing this:

My entry is:

```
<div class="number">30</div>
<div class="number">80</div>
<div class="number">10</div>
<div class="number">20</div>
<div class="number">90</div>
```

I need to output:

```
<div class="number" style="width:30%;">30</div>
<div class="number" style="width:80%;">80</div>
<div class="number" style="width:10%;">10</div>
<div class="number" style="width:20%;">20</div>
<div class="number" style="width:90%;">90</div>
```

I tried multiple things using .html(), .text(), parseInt and each()

Comment: Please show the code you tried and tell us what went wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a callback returning the desired width (in your case the text inside the element) as the second argument to the **[`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-function)** function:

```
$('.number').css('width', function() {
    return $(this).text() + '%';
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
$(".number").each(function() {
    var num = parseInt( $(this).text(), 10 );
    $(this).css("width", num + "%");
});
```

Comment: don't forget the percent sign `num+'%'`